# Is it necessary and best practice to reassign a variable to cast it to a new type?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

If we have a PHP array and want to cast it to an object, is it necessary to reassign the variable? and is there any performance benefits to this?

```
$key_value = ('key1'=>'value1' , 'key2'=>'value2');

$key_value = (object)$key_value; //We can reassign as an object

//Is there a way to, without reassigning, just cast the type of the already assigned variable?
//Is this advantageous in terms of performance?
(object)$key_value; //is this the correct syntax, considering it is even possible?
```

In most cases this is probably irrelevant, but it got me curious towards the theory behind it.

Comment: So try this code and tell us.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for your answer, I'm interested in the theory behind it as stated in the question.

Comment: I think performance hits are negligible. Casting is on the order of CPU cycles, which take less than 1 nanosecond to do. If you set out nanoseconds to other "trivial" tasks like looking up a file, that is orders of magnitude smaller and you will probably not notice it ever: https://twitter.com/rzezeski/status/398306728263315456

Comment: This is actually 2 questions - the first of which,*"If we have a PHP array and want to cast it to an object, is it necessary to reassign the variable?"* can be simply answered - nope. And the second, *"is there any performance benefits to this?"* is probably going to be answered with some kind of digital shrug - *meh* maybe? The difference will be minimal, possibly worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`settype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) is the only way to change the type of a variable in-place. Every other mechanism returns a new value instead.